# Best design for user leaderboard scores in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble with the design of database for my game, users of the game have 3 score parameters that are weighted differently, scores are results of specific actions (did P, or did Q, or did L) within the app. So user would look something like this:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "531f14324fe3ba6360335230" },
  "p": 88,
  "q": 0,
  "l": 10,
  "totalScore":8.9
}
```

where p, q, l are different scores that have different weights.

I want to query information based on weekly/monthly activity of user, which means that users that got highest score in p, q, l scores will be top users of the current week.

I am totally failing to understand how to make proper architecture to both support date querying by weeks/months and support weighted calculation of the scores in efficient way assuming that I also want to make a leaderboard with surrounding users AND to have a POSITION of current user

```
-----------------q--------p--------l------
4. user121      25       5         0
5. currentUser  5        7        28
6. user77       3        2        43
-----
```

Would appreciate help a lot.

**UPD:**
So this is the rough draft of the design

I have actions collection, which contains documents for each usergenerated action, smth like this:

```
{
    id: ObjectId,
    type:'q',
    time: DATE,
    userId: USER_ObjectId,
    entityId: ENTITY_ObjectId
}
```

the same goes for other types.

So when action takes places in a game - I create such document and increment proper type field in scores document for user.
After this I calculate totalScore field based on my formula:

```
totalscore = q + p/10 + l/100
```

Now I can query and sort by total score, but it doesnt have any data about whether this score is for the last seven days or not, still have no clue how to achieve this.

Comment: Was there something in the answer that does not suit your needs? You have not responded.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be on the right track as per the last update, but I might offer a few "tweeks" to the design as well as address the date range part of the question.

While you can do nice things with `populate` using mongoose, it is still worth remembering that the sort of "joining" this does is only simulated, in that what actually happens is that additional queries are made to the database in order to retrieve the "related" items.

As such, when using MongoDB it is a very good idea to keep the information you want to use in the same collection. So for the simple example here, I'm going to go with keeping the "username" in these "event" type of entries. I do this because that is the information that will be used when summarizing this. So documents for the "events" (what I am calling them ) appear something like this:

```
{ 
    "userId": 123, 
    "username": "user1", 
    "type": "q", 
    "time": ISODate("2014-04-07T03:56:33.488Z")
},
{ 
    "userId": 123, 
    "username": "user1", 
    "type": "p", 
    "time": ISODate("2014-04-07T03:56:33.488Z")
},
{ 
    "userId": 456, 
    "username": "user2", 
    "type": "p", 
    "time": ISODate("2014-04-07T03:56:33.488Z")
}
```

Of course with additional fields but these are the ones we will focus on.

To bring these together within a date range you can do something like this:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    // Match the date range required
    { "$match": {
        "time": { 
            "$gte": new Date("2014-04-07"), 
            "$lt": new Date("2014-04-14") 
        }
    }},

    // Group and Reshape the matching documents
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$userId",
        "username": { "$first": "$username" },
        "q" : { "$sum": { "$eq": [ "$type", "q" ] } },
        "p" : { "$sum": { "$eq": [ "$type", "p" ] } },
        "l" : { "$sum": { "$eq": [ "$type", "l" ] } }
    }},

    // Project to get a "score" value
    { "$project": {
        "username": 1,
        "p": 1,
        "q": 1,
        "l": 1,
        "score": { "$add": [
            "$q",
            { "$cond": [
                "$p",
                { "$divide": [ "$p", 10 ] },
                0
            ]},
            { "$cond": [
                "$l",
                { "$divide": [ "$l", 10 ] },
                0
            ]},
        ]} 
    }},

    // Sort the results by the "score" descending
    { "$sort": { "score": -1 } },

    // Optionally limit the results
    { "$limit": 10 }

])
```

So all of that groups the results per user from the "event" based entries within the time period, calculates a total score ( being careful to not divide by 0 ), and then sorts the results so the highest score is on top.

You can even do a similar query to find the highest placed user from each week or other time interval:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    // Match the date range required - one year as a sample
    { "$match": {
        "time": { 
            "$gte": new Date("2014-01-01"), 
            "$lt": new Date("2015-01-01") 
        }
    }},


    // Group and Reshape the matching documents
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "week": { "$week": "$time" },
            "userId": "$userId"
        },
        "username": { "$first": "$username" },
        "q" : { "$sum": { "$eq": [ "$type", "q" ] } },
        "p" : { "$sum": { "$eq": [ "$type", "p" ] } },
        "l" : { "$sum": { "$eq": [ "$type", "l" ] } }
    }},

    // Project to get a "score" value
    { "$project": {
        "username": 1,
        "p": 1,
        "q": 1,
        "l": 1,
        "score": { "$add": [
            "$q",
            { "$cond": [
                "$p",
                { "$divide": [ "$p", 10 ] },
                0
            ]},
            { "$cond": [
                "$l",
                { "$divide": [ "$l", 10 ] },
                0
            ]},
        ]} 
    }},

    // Sort by highest score for each week
    { "$sort": { "_id.week": 1, "score": -1 } },

    // Group again to get the highest value in each week
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.week",
        "userId": { "$first": "$_id.userId" },
        "username": { "$first": "$username" },
        "q": { "$first": "$q" },
        "p": { "$first": "$p" },
        "l": { "$first": "$l" },
        "score": { "$first": "$score" }, 
    }}

])
```

If you require running totals then you are probably best off "pre-aggregating" those results into another collection and keeping the discreet weeks in terms of overall performance, or even indeed keeping the running totals by week or whatever timeframe suits you best.

So for reference, there is a bit to take in here, but the main documentation can be viewed for the various [aggregation framework operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and especially the [Date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) as these will allow you to "group" together on different components of the date, being either week, month, day, hour or year.

Comment: Thanks!
But I dont see how this design can get me surrounding users by score?